# seach-mailbox group mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange, microsoft-office-365

How do you search a group mailbox.

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "groupbox@mail.com" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Hello"' -TargetMailbox me@mail.com -TargetFolder "Inbox"
```

When I try to search the group mailbox I get the error message.
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'groupbox@mail.com' couldn't be found on
'xxxxxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM'.

But when I search for the mailbox I can find it.

```
Get-Mailbox -GroupMailbox -Identity "groupbox@mail.com"
```

Is it because it is a group mailbox?
How do you search a group mailbox?

Comment: Just to rule out other problems - have you tried your command with a non-group mailbox? I am not using 365, so I cannot test your scenario here.

Comment: I have test the scripts in my environment and get the same results as yours. But if I change the identity to a user mailbox the operation can be performed successfully. So I guess that group mailbox is not supported in search-mailbox. However, you can create a in-place search in EAC to get the search results

Comment: Have you tried piping to Search-Mailbox? `Get-Mailbox -GroupMailbox -Identity "groupbox@mail.com" | Search-Mailbox ...` leaving off the -Identity parameter on Search-Mailbox?

Comment: I have not issue with regular mailboxes.
I have also tried to pipe the Get-Mailbox result into Search-Mailbox and get the same issue

Comment: Have you tried getting results from In place-Ediscovery search Via EAC > Compliance ?

Comment: I don't have time to look at this anymore. But I was going down the path Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.2

Answer (score 0):

group mailboxes are not supported by the search-mailbox commandlet.

Use the eDiscovery/Content search in the Security and Compliance center.